# Apex Class zero code coverage

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am very new to Apex.. a day into it so sorry for my ingornace. What I am trying to do is return a list of my accounts and then review the contract dates of the account(Contract_Expiration__c). Depending on that date it should update a custome field (
update_active_status_text__c)  with null, Active, or Void.

I am not getting any error but I am not getting any code coverage. Any help will go a long way.

Thanks in advance

Apex Class

```
public class update_active_status {
    public static VOID update_active_statustest(){
        list<Account> myaccount = [SELECT Id, Contract_Expiration__c, update_active_status_text__c FROM Account WHERE CMS_Customer_Type__c = 'Enterprise' or CMS_Customer_Type__c = 'cloud'];
            for(Account a: myaccount){
           if (a.Contract_Expiration__c == null ){ 
                   a.update_active_status_text__c = null;
                   update a;
               } else if (a.Contract_Expiration__c >= Date.today().addDays(-60)) {
                a.update_active_status_text__c = 'Active';
                   update a;
               } else if (a.Contract_Expiration__c < Date.today().addDays(-60)) {
                a.update_active_status_text__c = 'Void';
                   update a;
               } else {
                a.update_active_status_text__c = 'Void';
                  update a;
               }    
        }
     }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public class testupdate_active_status {
    static testMethod void myupdate_active_statusTest() {
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert(acc);

        Date d = Date.today();
        acc.Contract_Expiration__c = d;
        update(acc);

        acc.update_active_status_text__c = 'Active';
        update(acc);

        acc = [Select update_active_status_text__c From Account Where Id = : acc.Id];
        System.assertEquals('Active', acc.update_active_status_text__c);

    }

    static testMethod void setToNull() {
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert(acc);

        Date d = Date.today();
        acc.Contract_Expiration__c = d;
        update(acc);

        acc.Contract_Expiration__c = null;
        update(acc);

        acc = [Select update_active_status_text__c From Account Where Id = : acc.Id];
        System.assertEquals(null, acc.update_active_status_text__c);

    }

    static testMethod void createWithDate() {
        Date d = Date.today().addDays(-70);
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account', Contract_Expiration__c = d);
        insert(acc);

        acc.update_active_status_text__c = 'Void';
        update(acc);

        acc = [Select update_active_status_text__c From Account Where Id = : acc.Id];
        System.assertEquals('Void', acc.update_active_status_text__c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test isn't actually using any of the methods in the class you wrote. Perhaps:

```
@isTest
public class testupdate_active_status {
    static testMethod void myupdate_active_statusTest() {
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert(acc);

        Date d = Date.today();
        acc.Contract_Expiration__c = d;
        update(acc);

        testupdate_active_status.update_active_statustest();   // Call your new method!

        acc = [Select update_active_status_text__c From Account Where Id = : acc.Id];
        System.assertEquals('Active', acc.update_active_status_text__c);

    }

    static testMethod void setToNull() {
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert(acc);

        Date d = Date.today();
        acc.Contract_Expiration__c = d;
        update(acc);

        testupdate_active_status.update_active_statustest();   // Call your new method!

        acc = [Select update_active_status_text__c From Account Where Id = : acc.Id];
        System.assertEquals(null, acc.update_active_status_text__c);

    }

    static testMethod void createWithDate() {
        Date d = Date.today().addDays(-70);
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account', Contract_Expiration__c = d);
        insert(acc);

        testupdate_active_status.update_active_statustest();   // Call your new method!

        acc = [Select update_active_status_text__c From Account Where Id = : acc.Id];
        System.assertEquals('Void', acc.update_active_status_text__c);
    }
}
```

Your new class's job is to update the `update_active_status_text__c`...you're bypassing that job when you manually/explicitly update that field yourself (`acc.update_active_status_text__c = 'Active'; update(acc);`).